# in typescript, What's the difference between these two index signature type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

I want to set the object attribute to be either a boolean value or an boolean array value depending on the props.

But it shows an error when the key value is received as a variable rather than a literal string value.

I don't know the difference between two.

```
export interface State {
    a: {
        [key: string]: any[];
    };
    b: {
        [key: string]: boolean | boolean[];
    };
}

const state:State = {
    a: {},
    b: {},
}


const key:string = "test key";

// this works
let test1 = typeof state.b["test key"] === 'object' && state.a["test key"][0];
// type error : Property '0' does not exist on type 'boolean | boolean[]
let test2 = typeof state.b[key] === 'object' && state.b[key][0];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first index signature works because you are using `any`. So `state.a["test key"]` will be any, and you can do anything with `any`, including indexing into it. So it's not really surprising this actually works.

The reason your second example doesn't work, is because typescript will not narrow index access with a variable. So this works:

```
export interface State {
    [key: string]: boolean | boolean[];
}

const state:State = {
}


let test2 = typeof state["test key"] === 'object' && state["test key"][0];
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgZRk1TgG8AoOKuAbQGtgBPALjgGcYpkBzAXVYBGECABtgmJHAA+cIaPFIavANzkAvuXLYISDuyKpmhYngC8ZdZvJj4qDgCY45mIzDAI6fSZoAiO-AZGH14nU3MAcggBACtgbBhwuAAyJK9UX384QOCaAAYVIA)

The alternatives are to use a type assertion, or put the result of the idex operation in a variable and narrow that:

```
const key:string = "test key";
// This does not work
let test2 = typeof state[key] === 'object' && state[key][0];

// This works
let keyValue  = state[key];
let test3 = typeof keyValue === 'object' && keyValue[0];


// Or with a assertion
let test4 = typeof state[key] === 'object' && (state[key] as boolean[])[0];
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgZRk1TgG8AoOKuAbQGtgBPALjgGcYpkBzAXVYBGECABtgmJHAA+cIaPFIavANzkAvuXLYISDuyKpmhYngC8ZdZu274DFhy5JuccwCJUeu69UB6H3AAVAAsENjgAEwhgMKQIeAB3aDpyMXgPGAAmFzgYRjBgCHR9E3omXhdTcwByCAEAK2BsGCq4ADJW4tRSxl4aAAYVTT9AkLDEqDo2FOBbJgA1TBEAVzxsjhK7QdSc6JgAZmzc-MK4OwXls0q4GvrG5raOs8WV-sGh-wB5KDh4hBgguCYQFsNhoGAIHTTNK7AAshzyBSK6y6mwq1VqDSaLXacAAFMjgN1ypgwnIxBIlABKV7KIA)